Move Bone Along Path with Constraints
Trying to move multiple bones along a path when another bone rotates. When the forearm bone rotates, Bones 1 - 3 should move down along the path into the box. I can set the bones to the path, but I don't know how to translate the Forearm bone's rotation to Bones 1 - 3.


